# Transfer learning from a custom model trained with different image sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have a custom model trained initially on VGG16 using transfer learning. However, it was initially trained on images with a smaller input size. Now, I am using images with bigger sizes, therefore I'd like to grab the first model and take advantage of what it has learned but now with new dataset.

More specifically:

---

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 160, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 160, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 80, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 80, 128)       73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 80, 128)       147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 40, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 40, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 40, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 40, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 20, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 20, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 20, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 16, 20, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 8, 10, 512)        0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 8, 10, 512)        2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 8, 10, 512)        2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 8, 10, 512)        2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 4, 5, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 10240)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 16)                163856    
                                                                 
 output (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17
```

The problem is that this model already includes an input layer of 128x160, and I'd like to change it to 384x288 for transfer learning.

The above is my first model, I now would like to do transfer learning again but with a different dataset that has an input of size 384x288 and I'd like to use a softmax for two classes instead.

So, what i want to do is a transfer learning from the custom model on a different dataset, So I need to change the input size and retrain the new model with my own data

How can I do a transfer learning on the model above but with a new dataset and different classification layer in the output?

Comment: You can fix the weights of the convolution layers, replace the dense layers and train them. The size of image doesn't matter, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65519862/9758790) and [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57639).

Comment: I must confess that until now I was only able to remove the flatten and both dense layers. I was not able to find how would I retrain the model with a different input size after getting the model weights. For instance, to remove the last layers I do: `loaded_model = Model(loaded_model.input, loaded_model.layers[-4].output)` and to get the weights `loaded_model = model.get_weights()`. Then, what do I do next, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very simple solution to my problem and now I am able to train it with different data and diferent classification layers:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential


old_model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/old_model.h5")
old_model = Model(old_model.input, old_model.layers[-4].output) # Remove the classification, dense and flatten layers


base_model = Sequential() # Create a new model from the 2nd layer and all the convolutional blocks
for layer in old_model.layers[1:]:
  base_model.add(layer)

for layer_number, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers):
  print(layer_number, layer.name, layer.trainable)


# Perform transfer learning
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(384, 288, 3)),
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps:

1. Build another instance of model, don't forget to change it's input shape.
2. Copy the weights of the shared convolutional layers from the loaded model, and set them to be non_trainable.

```
for new_layer, layer in zip(new_model.layers[0:-4], model.layers[0:-4]):
    new_layer.set_weights(layer.get_weights())
    new_layer.trainable = False
```

3. Add new dense layers and train the whole model.

---

Further reading:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65519862/9758790) and [This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/57639/transfer-learning-on-new-image-size) expain how you can change the input shape.
2. [Keras guides](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/) shows how you can do transfer learning with Keras. Under [This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/21734) are some useful code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions for it.

**As suggested by many and a very simple solution:**

1. Downscale the image to the input size of pretrained model
2. Change the final layer of pretrained model and freeze the rest of the layers
3. Train the model [transfer learning]
4. Once the model converges you can unfreeze the full model and train the full model again at a very low learning rate [finetuning]

However, in the above approach you are not able to take advantage of higher resolution images you have.

#### Using pretrained model as feature extractor

Another approach is to use the pretrained model just as feature extractor and train a seperate model on high resolution images. Finally use the features from both the pretrained model as well as your trained model to do the final predictions. The high level idea is as below:

[image]

#### Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

low_res_image_size = (150, 150, 3)
hig_res_image_size = (320, 240, 3)
n_classes = 4

# Load your pretrained model train on low resolution images
base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=low_res_image_size)
# Freeze the pretrained model
base_model.trainable = False

# Unfreezed model to be trained on high resolution images
model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=hig_res_image_size)
model.trainable = True

# Downscale images
downscale_layer = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(
    low_res_image_size[0], low_res_image_size[1], 
    interpolation='bilinear',  crop_to_aspect_ratio=False)

# Create model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=hig_res_image_size)

downscaled_inputs = downscale_layer(inputs)
features = base_model(downscaled_inputs, training=False)
features = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(features)

x = model(inputs, training=True)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([features, x])
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes)(concatted)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
# Train on some random data
model.fit(
    np.random.random((100,*hig_res_image_size)), 
    np.random.randint(0, n_classes, 100), epochs=3)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/3
4/4 [==============================] - 4s 553ms/step - loss: 8.7033
Epoch 2/3
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 554ms/step - loss: 9.0746
Epoch 3/3
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 553ms/step - loss: 9.0746
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f559a104650>
```

As and added step, after the model converges you and also unfreeze all the layers and train the full model again using a very low learning rate. Just keep an eye on overfitting.

Comment: the custom pretrained model, already includes an input layer of size (128x160x3) which was used to train it originally and that is the main reason as to why i am struggling to employ transfer learning, unlike keras pretrained models such as VGG16 where you can specify your own input size. As I don't know if I need to remove from this pretrained model the input layer and if so, how would i do that and how do I change it after?

Comment: @xnok why not just load the pretrained model along with the input layer and change the `low_res_image_size` to `(128x160x3)`. It should still work because there are no trainable layers on the top of input layer. `base_model` should point to your loaded pretrained model along with the input layers and make sure to freeze it.

Answer (score -1):

Copy your model to the another model (transfer learning), and then update the new model in the way you want to use it. Change input size, change activation functions, whatever you wanna do.

Comment: Is there an example on how to  do it?